# My label does not change in viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

hi I am a beginner programmer swift

My code is:

I need change label, why label does not change in viewcontroller?

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(requset) {
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        println("eror=\(error)")
        return
    }
    println("responce = \(response)")

    let responcsestring = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    println("responce data = \(responcsestring)")

    self.lable.text = "hello"

}
```

thanks

Comment: Have you connected the reference of that label in the interface builder? (IBOulet)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that code isn't running in the main thread, so although the label is getting updated, the UI doesn't know about it. Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
{
    self.lable.text = "hello"
}
```

...and hopefully you'll see the label update!

Simon

Comment: Or higher level API `NSOperationQueue` ;) `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock() { self.label.text = "hello" }`

Answer (score 0):

is the object named lable? If not try `self.label.text = "hello";` might be you made just a typo

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what your program does with your code?

Comment: You know why need "self" ?

Comment: I suspect it's to call the proper thread for the functions needed. (Not sure, new to swift myself)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you spelled request wrong? `let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(requset) {`